# How can I save a Cypher query *permanently*?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

How can I save my Cypher query ***permanently***?
Let me explain my problem: I save the query with the button "save" (you can see the "star button" at the top of this [image](http://www.apcjones.com/talks/2014-03-26_Neo4j_London/images/neo4j_browser.png)), but when I copy or move the folder of database I loose every query I saved.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Cypher queries are software.  They're source code.  The web interface to neo4j gives you an easy way to enter them, and save them temporarily and so on.  But I would recommend that you look at cypher queries you want to save as source code; don't use the web interface to try to do this.

Fortunately, if you look at your cypher queries as source code, you can use any of the thousands of tools available for source code; IDEs, version tracking (such as git) and so on.  The bottom line though is that your queries are software in and of themselves, and should be tracked like software (if you intend to modify them and use them over and over through time).

If it's quick and dirty, save your cypher queries in `myQueries.cypher` in your home user directory, and they'll always be there for you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the cypher queries are saved in your browser's local storage.

Which is tied to the URL (e.g. localhost:7474) so even if you move the storage file it shouldn't affect your stored queries.

If you want to store your queries in the db, you can check out my server extension: [cypher-rs](https://github.com/jexp/cypher-rs) which allows something like that.